# A NAND flash sector suddenly goes bad. What happens to the file using that sector?

Tags: sd

I can read a lot about how NAND flash can be checked for bad sectors, which are flagged and won't be read/written to in the future, but happens at the moment a sector goes bad? Any file that was using that sector would have to be lost wouldn't it?

What happens to that file? Does it just disappear from the filesystem entirely or does it remain in the inode table but is now corrupt and unreadable?

Assume the file system is UBIFS if that's important.

---

EDIT: Here's some background for *why* I ask the question: I have some devices with UBIFS and I've seen two instances of a file disappearing (different file and different device each time). The file in both cases was just not there on the filesystem anymore. But I don't have a good explanation for how it happened.

I wanted to know if it was within the realm of possibility that a block on the NAND flash just went 'bad' (I was thinking in the sense that it was no longer capable of being written to/read to) and took the whole file with it.

Comment: One question would be if blocks routinely "go bad" in the sense of suddenly reading back longstanding data erroneously, or if they "go bad" in the sense of being unable to write new data and read it back reliably after an erase has been performed to re-use that block.

Answer (score 3):

Information is typically written to flash memories using forward error correcting codes; in addition to the 2048 bits that make up the data for a sector, some additional "ECC" bit values will be computed based upon the contents of those 2048 bits.  When a sector is read, those ECC bit values will be computed again and compared with the values that were stored previously.  If they don't match, that would imply that one or more bits have changed between the time the data was written and the time it was read back.  If only a small number of bits has changed, it may be possible to infer what the correct data should have been.

Note that at the raw hardware level, if a device stores four bits per cell, anything which corrupts one bit within a cell may be likely to corrupt others, but individual memory cells are essentially independent.  Consequently, it may be much more likely that one or two independent memory cells would go bad than that more than four would go bad.  If an error-correcting code is designed so that more than four memory cells would have to prevent perfect recovery of the stored data, a chip would be much more likely to discover that a sector is going bad without losing data, than to lose data because a sector went bad.

One nasty little caveat with this, however, is that many memory chips implement their own error correcting codes internally in addition to whatever is implemented in the controller outside.  Depending upon how those codes are implemented, they may prevent the controller from discovering that memory cells are starting to return corrupt data until so many bits have gone bad as to prevent recovery.  I'm don't know of any way to identify flash drives where such a thing would be a problem, however.

Answer (score 2):

A bit, byte or sector going bad has three results. Information might not be writable to that sector (write error), might not be readble (read access/io error), or might be corrupt (might pass a normal r/w request but future access returns garbled data).

But none of that should affect whether your file is seen. Why? Because a file system uses a file map and inodes to track file to sector mappings and file names/type/creation/mod/access dates/etc. And it keeps multiple copies of that. This is on top of whatever media driver is used, and whatever error orrection the medium uses at the physical level.

For a bad sector to make a file disappear would require the file to disappear from the file map.

What is more likely is files disappearing from a virus, or caching errors from not flushing (I mean properly ejecting the disk before removing it from the pc).